# How do I get my DataBase First EF 6.1 Entities to become a change tracking proxies

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm struggling to get my model's entities to be change tracker proxies rather than utilize snap shot change detection.

My entities are created by the EF designer and have been otherwise unmodified. I followed the steps in Programming Entity Framework: DbContext but my entities never seem to inherit the IEntitiyWithChangeTracker (though they are in fact DynamicProxies).

Can anyone enumerate the steps to make an entity created by the DataBase First EF 6.1 designer into a change tracker proxy? I assume that modification of the classes must be made outside the designer, nothing will be automatic.

Comment: It appears that the entities created by the DataBase First EF 6.1 designer include navigation properties that are virtual and collection navigation properties that are initialized in the class constructor. Without modification, the classes support dynamicproxies for LazyLoading. However, to get them to be ChangeTracker proxies, you need to make all the properties virtual and remove initialization of the navigation collection properties from the class constructor. Having done this though, the dynamicproxies created are not IEntityWithChangeTracker.

Comment: You can use the technique in this article to show that changes are being tracked (and I'm pretty sure this method doesn't trigger a call to DetectChanges) [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee835846(v=vs.100).aspx . So, I believe that ChangeTracker proxies are being created but not sure why not of IEntityWithChangeTracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer lies in using the correct Namespace for IEntityWithChangeTracker. In EF6.x if you test with System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithChangeTracker your entity will return true. Thanks Fred Bao of MSFT